# How to display ONLY 1 record in a form?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have a modal popup form in an Access 2007 project.

There is 1 row in the `Config` table and each text box in the form is bound to a column in `Config`.

**Form > Properties > Date:**

```
Record Source = SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Config

Allow Edits = Yes
```

With `Allow Additions = No`, the form just displays the background - no text boxes.

With `Allow Additions = Yes`, the form displays a new record every time.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem:

*Properties > Data > Data Entry* was `Yes` - changing this to `No` fixed the problem!